# Confusion in Burnside's proof that any $2$-generated group of exponent $3$ is finite?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm reading a proof of Burnside's theorem that groups of exponent $3$ are finite, but have some problems.

> Let $G=\langle x,y:z^3=1\rangle$ be a group generated by $x$ an $y$ with exponent $3$. Let $a=yxy^{-1}$ and $b=y^{-1}xy$. Then
>   $$
> xab=xyxy^{-1}y^{-1}xy=xyxyxy=(xy)^3=1.
> $$
>   Similarly, $bax=1$, so $ab=ba$. Then $1=xab=abx=xba=bax$, so from $abx=xba$, we have $bx=xb$, and similarly $ax=xa$.
>
> Let $N=\langle x,a,b\rangle$, which is normal and abelian, hence finite. If $b=x$, then $x=y^{-1}xy$ implies $yx=xy$ so $G$ is abelian and we are done. If $b=x^2$, then $x=1$. And if $b=x^3$, $x=1$, and there is nothing to prove.
>
> So suppose $b$ is not a power of $x$. Then $x$ and $b$ are independent commuting elements in $N$ , and since $a=x^{-1}b^{-1}$, $N=\langle x,b\rangle$, so $|N|=3^2$. Then $G/N\simeq\langle y\rangle$...

I have two issues: Why does $b=x^2$ imply $x=1$? This means $x^2=y^{-1}xy$, or $yx^2=xy$ but I have no reason to see $x=1$. Also, why is $G/N\simeq\langle y\rangle?$ I think it is clear $G/N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\langle y\rangle$, but couldn't $G/N$ be trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to prove G is finite, your confusion is not necessary. When you got N is finite normal subgroup of G, yo know that G/N is a group of order no greater than 3, and G is finite.

Comment: I'm aware that it's not necessary, but I'd still like to understand the details out of curiosity.

Comment: Well, let me give some explanation: If $b=x^2$, then $y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}$, and then $(y^2)^{_1}xy^2=x$. This means $x$ commutes with $y^2$. Note $y$ is of order 3, so $x$ commutes with $y$, and $b=x$, contrary our assumption $b\ne x$.

Comment: Now for the second issure, if $G/N$ is trivial, then $y \in N$. But we already know that $N$ is abelian, and then $G$ is abelian. So $x$ commutes with $y$ and  $b=y^{-1}xy=x$, contrary to our assumption $b$ is not a power of $x$.

Comment: By the way, from which paper your proof come? I know this result, but I never reading the original paper about this result.

Comment: The proof is from Burnside's 1902 paper "On an unanswered question on discontinuous groups."